# send value from swift app to pebble app

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I have created a simple swift app that shows your current speed, and would like to create a pebble app that would talk to the iOS app and display the speed to. So my question is, how can I send a value from a swift app to an C/JS pebble app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, Pebble apps are written with C/JavaScript *or* C/Java  *or* C/Objective-C. If you go with the C/Objective-C route you should be able to use Swift code. But you say that you want to communicate with a C/JavaScript app, which is confusing. Could you expand on your question a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Pebble is yet to provide a SDK for swift applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a way to do it with swift.

Create a dictionary object then send it to the pebble watch.

```
    let dictionary: NSDictionary
    dictionary = [key : value, key : value, key : value....]


    watch.appMessagesPushUpdate(dictionary as! [NSNumber : AnyObject]) { (watch, dictionary, error) in
        if ((error == nil))
        {
            NSLog("Successfully sent message.");
        } else if ((error) != nil)
        {
            NSLog("Error sending message: \(error)");
        }
    }
}
```